# Clear Firefox cookie without restarting?

Tags: firefox

I have to clear some cookies and then restart firefox. I can delete specific cookies in firefox but I have to restart for them to take effect.

It seems that when I delete the cookie using the Cookie Manager extension it does not remove it from the cache(if there is one). Restarting firefox solves the problem but is not efficient.

Edit:

OK, guys, please cut it out with all the "deleting cookies" addons. I have installed an addon that does it and do not need 15 more that do the same(unless you happen to know one is specifically better).

It seems that these cookie managers only delete the cookies from file and that something else maybe going on. I have blocked the site from using cookies but it still remembers me. BUT if I change my gmail login then it swaps over to the new user. So either it is hooking into the gmail cookies to keep track of who is logged in or somehow using javascript.

Now that I think about it I bet it is sniffing the gmail cookies since it is changing with gmail login changes.

So, is there any way to lock down a website from looking at other cookies? (a sort of sandbox for that site alone?)

Obviously running another web brower or using some other method might work but I want to keep it as unobtrusive as possible.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? Clearing cookies is a simple as pressing CTRL+SHIFT+DEL. If the related pages are still open in tabs, you may need to close them first. There should be no need to restart Firefox.

Comment: When I delete cookies through Option->Privacy->Remove Individual Cookies, the changes take effect right away for me.  I know this works, because I do it frequently with the NYTimes cookies.

Comment: How do you know that they are not deleted?

Comment: Don’t bother. This guy doesn’t provide any information and expects people to magically read his mind about what the problem is. Worse, he’ll blame you if your best guess doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Options->Privacy->Show Cookies. Are they all still there?

there is an option to delete them all from here as well, try that one instead.

Update your version of Fire Fox.

Answer (score 0):

I use ["View Cookies"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-cookies/) extension, it provides a tab in "View Page Info", and possibility to remove any cookie from page cookies' list. It worked fine when I needed to have cookies removed to test my web-apps; see if it works for you (and if it supports your Firefox ver.)

Comment: I don't know what it would be different from the cookie manager I have. It seems the issue is not the cookie itself as I disabled them and the site still "remembers". I think it is persisting the state through javascript.

Comment: It sounds strange. Try clearing cache along with cookies in that case (via ctrl+shift+del).

Answer (score 0):

Suggested tool: CookieCuller add-on. This add-on allow you to keep cookies you want and suppress the other with a simple ONE click within the CookieCuller extension windows (or at startup)

EDIT

- To know which site add which cookie try *NirSoft's WebCookiesSniffer*
- The CookieCuller add-on have an option to prevent deleted cookies to
  be used again
- There's some other cookies: Flash cookies or *LSO* (Local Shared
  Object). These cookies can be deleted in different and inobtrusive
  way by Better Privacy add-on for Firefox

Comment: Ok, I used that and deleted all the cookies that were showing up in WebCookiesSniffer but it still remembers. Either it is using javascript, or a flash cookie, or something else.  I have some of the addons but disabled them for the site to get it to work. Is there any addon that would allow me to see exactly what a website is adding to the browser that persists after closing the web page? (cookies being the obvious one but I'm pretty sure I've blocked them all(at least what webcookiesniffer is telling me)).